# I'm a bit stuck in python

Tags: python

So i have to write a function that adds the sum of the two last numbers in a list together and adds this sum to the list. I have to do this 3 times, i could either do it without a loop or with a loop, i chose to do the difficult path, because i want to challenge myself, but i'm a bit stuck.

When i run the code with input       print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))       it returns the correct value, but when i input      print(append_sum([2, 5]))       it only return 2, 5, 7

Full code is below:

```
#Write your function here
def append_sum(lst):
  i = 0
  for i in lst:
    lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
    i += 1
    if i == 3:
      return lst

#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: your for loop iterates over the list lst, which is not necessary, and in general something to avoid when changing the list inside the for loop. Just do `for i in range(3):` and in your case i is an element of lst not an index.

Answer (score 0):

You need not iterate every item in list.

```
def append_sum(lst):
    repetitions = 3
    for i in range(repetitions):
        lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
    return lst

print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `i` variable in the for loop. Change the name to a different variable.

```py
#Write your function here
def append_sum(lst):
  counter = 0
  for i in lst:
    lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
    counter += 1
    if counter == 3:
      return lst

#Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

It is generally a really bad practice to use `a, b, c, x, y, z, i, j, k` etc as variable names, as it makes the code less readable. Please use better variable names.

```py
# Write your function here
def append_sum(numbers_list):
    counter = 0
    for number in numbers_list:
        numbers_list.append(numbers_list[-1] + numbers_list[-2])
        counter += 1
        if counter == 3:
            return numbers_list


# Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(append_sum([2, 5]))
```

In fact, for this case, you don't even need to iterate over the list.

```py
# Write your function here
def append_sum(numbers_list):
    if len(numbers_list) < 2:
        raise Exception("List must have at least two numbers")

    for counter in range(1, 3 + 1):
        numbers_list.append(numbers_list[-1] + numbers_list[-2])
        if counter == 3:
            return numbers_list


# Uncomment the line below when your function is done
print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: Oh okay thank you for clarifying! And i will use better variables!

Comment: If the answer was sufficient to your queries, consider upvoting and accepting it as the answer to your question.